# Has already been added to the window manager (Used in BroadCastReceiver)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-broadcast

Sometimes in some devices I face this crash, has already been added to the window manager

firstly I call `initiateViews()` then I call ShowView(param)

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
  public void initiateViews() {
    try {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        myview = li.inflate(R.layout.monthly_ride_request_layout, null);
        donutProgress = myview.findViewById(R.id.progresstimer);
        progressBar = myview.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        address = myview.findViewById(R.id.address);
        headText = myview.findViewById(R.id.txt_monthly_ride_head);
        headText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        headText.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.monthly_ride));
        km = myview.findViewById(R.id.km);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Then I call:

```
  private void ShowView(WindowManager.LayoutParams params) {
    try {
            viewhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    isRingingViewVisible = true;
                    wm.addView(myview, params);
                    StartTimer();
                }
            },1500);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

For adding Params

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private WindowManager.LayoutParams getLayoutParamsForOreoOrGreater() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
               /*         | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR*/
            , PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    return params;
}
```

Application Crash in this line `wm.addView(myview, params);`

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether the view is attached to window before calling `handler.post` to attach it later. The view ends up getting attached between your check and when the Looper processes your callback. You should move the check `if (view.getWindowToken() == null)` into the callback you pass to `post`, so this check happens immediately before you attempt to attach the view to a window.

Comment: i already see this answer but how it is possible to implement i code because i used in broadcastreceiver

Comment: Can you please set condition for view is null or not inside your initiateViews() and than call your method ShowView(param) from that method only, Instead of separate call.

Comment: yes i add the null check but still same error occur
 if (myview==null||wm==null){
                    initiateViews();
                    
                }